# how to return from the function with the object I just inserted?

Tags: apex, apexactionfunction

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static **Database.SaveResult** insertNewAccount(String nome) {
        if(nome != null){

            Contact novoregistro = new Contact(FirstName= nome,
                                               LastName='oliveira',
                                               Email='oliveira@example.com',
                                               Description='Contact of the day');

            Database.SaveResult results = Database.insert(novoregistro);
            return results;

        }else{
            //String reposta ='entro aqui no else';
            //return reposta;
            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi,
The inserted object is a Contact then you have to return a Contact. You can use this code below:

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static Contact insertNewAccount(String nome) {
        if(nome != null){

            Contact novoregistro = new Contact(FirstName= nome,
                                             LastName='oliveira',
                                             Email='oliveira@example.com',
                                             Description='Contact of the day');

            insert novoregistro ;

            return novoregistro ;

        }else{

            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Also  add **@AuraEnabled**  above the method if you want to enable a Lightning component to access  the apex method

Answer (score 0):

I got it that way too.

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static Database.SaveResult insertNewAccount(String nome) {
        if(nome != null){
            Contact novoregistro = new Contact(FirstName= nome,
                                               LastName='oliveira',
                                               Email='oliveira@example.com',
                                               Description='Contact of the day');
            return Database.insert(novoregistro);
            //return results;
        }else{
            //String reposta ='entro aqui no else';
            //return reposta;
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea it works but after I'm afraid you can not access the information of the object. you will just able to get the id of the object via the getId() method . Have  a look  at [SaveResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm)